# Http image urls not showing in andriod native browser at Https domains

Tags: android, http, browser, https, stock

My domain is https://*******.com, When I try to display Http domain [image](http://earlylearning.momtrusted.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/preschool-counting-activity-with-pom-poms.jpg) in my https domain its not loading. When I check my browser console I got Mixed-content error and blocked image url.

When I access same page in chrome its works fine. When I check chrome console it shows the same message in warning state.

Can anyone say how to overcome this.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you have to make a request queue with your certificate to be able to load , chrome can redirect your link but in android it will make a validation error for security and you can't allow access to all hosts as from today(1/3/2017) google will not accept this type of connections

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SSL enabled website you must deliver all external content used on it through HTTPS aswell or most browsers will block that content and display a warning to the user.